# If $\partial _1 f(x,y)=\partial _2 f(x,y)$, then $f(x+d,y-d)=k$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ such that $\partial _1 f(x,y)=\partial _2
>  f(x,y)$ for all$(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Show that for all $x,y\in
> \mathbb{R}$ there is a $k\in \mathbb{R}$ with
>
> $f(x+d,y-d)=k$ for all $d\in \mathbb{R}$
>
> Why is there a $g\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that
>
> $f(x,y)=g(x+y)$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$

I already proved that if $\partial _{(y-x)}f(x+t(y-x))=0$ for all $t\in [0,1]$, then there is a $w\in \mathbb{R}^M$ such that $f(x+t(y-x))=w$ for all $t\in [0,1]$.

I somehow have to connect these statements to prove the highlighted one, I don't really see how this would work out, any ideas?

Comment: Such $k$ may depend on $(x,y)$?

Comment: I think so - why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$ and take $\vec v=(1,-1)$.

It is easy (and you have yet proved it) that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\vec v} f(x,y)=0$.

Indeed, as $f$ is differentiable, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\vec v}=\nabla f(x,y) \cdot \vec v=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$.

But $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\vec v} f(x,y)=\frac{d}{dt}F(t)$, where $F(t):=f((x,y)+t\vec v)$.

So you have that for fixed $(x,y)$, there is $k\in\Bbb R$ such that $F(t)=k$. So, for any $t\in\Bbb R$, $f(x+t,y-t)=k$.